# Why do I get an error when I compile the following code in GCC 4.9.2?

Tags: c++

```
int main() {
    int T;
    cin>>T;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < T ; ++i) {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    /*error:prog.cpp:41:6: error: name lookup of 'i' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]*/
    for(i = 0 ; i < T ; ++i) {
        cout<<Z(a[i])<<'\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I add `int` before `i` in the second for loop, the code runs perfectly.

NOTE: `a[]` and `Z()` are defined before `main()`.

I am new to GCC 4.9.2 . I have used Turbo C++ till now.

Comment: Because you have finally joined the 21st century. Though I guess you mean GCC 4.9.2.

Comment: This is why silly education systems teaching people pre-standard versions of languages from three cosmic eras ago is absurd.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You're making me feel very old. Reminds me of the good old days of `#define for if (false) else for`.

Comment: @AlanStokes: Personal age has nothing to do with it. A wise man moves with the times. You can be 80 and still be expected to write standard-compliant C++.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I do, to the best of my ability. But I started back in the era we're discussing, which seems so ancient.

Comment: @AlanStokes: You're not the only one! :)

Answer (score 5):

A long time ago in C++ your code was legal. An identifier like `i` declared in a for loop was still visible after the loop.

That changed, and by the time C++ was standardised in 1998 the scope of a variable declared in a for loop was just the body of the loop.

Your code is designed to work with the old system, and the compiler is telling you that that is no longer allowed.

Replace `for (i =` with `(for int i =` in the second loop and you're done. (And now you have two different variables called `i` rather than one.)

Comment: There have been a few other small changes since '98 too. I think you'll like them.  A good recent book on C++ might be interesting.

Answer (score 4):

The declaration if `i` only exists in the scope of the `for` loop. Once it exits, you lose the `i` declaration and cannot reuse it unless you re-declare it in subsequent loops.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < T ; ++i) {
    cin>>a[i];
} // scope of i ends here

for(i = 0 ; i < T ; ++i) { // loop has no idea what i is now
    cout<<Z(a[i])<<'\n';
}
```